# When is $BG \rightarrow BH \rightarrow BK$ a principal fibration?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces, short-exact-sequences

Let $1 \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow K \rightarrow 1$ be a short exact sequence of groups. Assume for simplicity that $G$ is finite, with the discrete topology (so $BG$ is a $K(G,1)$). Taking classifying spaces gives a fiber sequence
$$K(G,1) \simeq BG \rightarrow BH \rightarrow BK$$

When is this fiber sequence principal, i.e. when can I extend this to the right to a sequence
$$K(G,1) \rightarrow BH \rightarrow BK \overset{f}{\rightarrow} K(G,2)$$
s.t. $BH$ is the homotopy fiber of $f$?

I know that a sufficient condition is that the monodromy action of $\pi_1(BK)$ on the fiber $BG$ is trivial (in homology), but I'm not sure how that translates to the level of the exact sequence.

Comment: An obvious necessary condition is that $G$ is abelian, in case you have missed it.

Comment: I think $G$ is ablian and $K$ acts trivially on $G$ (which is equivalent to say that the extension is central) is the necessary and sufficient condition that you are looking for, since $H^2(K,G)$ is in one to one correspondence with the equivalence classes of central extensions.

Comment: Just entered to say what @user43326 has explained.

Comment: @user43326 That's what I thought as well - at least if $BK$ has the homotopy type of a $K(K,1)$ (bad notation clash, I know). Is it still necessary for $K$ to act trivially on $G$ if $BK$ is not aspherical?

Comment: Presumably yes, since $H^2(K,G)\cong BK,K(G,2)$ even when $K$ is not discrete, and this latter is supposed to correspond to central extensions (e.g. https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~schotten/LNP-cft-pdf/03_978-3-540-68625-5_Ch03_23-08-08.pdf. Remark 3.27) If $G$ is in the center of $H$, then $K$ itself, not just $\pi _1(BK)$, acts trivially

Comment: I meant $[BK,K(G,2)]$